# Perl: Using Text::CSV to print AoH

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I have an array of hashes (AoH) which looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Unit' => 'M',
            'Size' => '321',
            'User' => 'test'
          }
          {
            'Unit' => 'M'
            'Size' => '0.24'
            'User' => 'test1'
          }
          ...
        ];
```

How do I write my AoH to a CSV file with separators, to get the following result:

```
test;321M
test1;0.24M
```

I've already tried this code:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => ';' } );
$csv->print( $fh1, \@homefoldersize );
```

But I get

```
HASH(0x....)
```

in my CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes I did, I tried to print array but got `HASH(0x......)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty fundamentally - `CSV` is an array based data structure - it's a vaguely enhanced version of `join`. But the thing you need for this job is `print_hr` from `Text::CSV`.

First you need to set your header order:

```
 $csv->column_names (@names);          # Set column names for getline_hr ()
```

Then you can use

```
 $csv -> print_hr ( *STDOUT, $hashref );
```

E.g.

```
 $csv -> column_names ( qw ( User Size Unit ) ); 
 foreach my $hashref ( @homefoldersize ) {
      $csv -> print_hr ( *STDOUT, $hashref ); 
 }
```

As you want to concatenate a couple of your columns though, that's *slightly* harder - you'll need to transform the data first, because otherwise `Size` and `Unit` are separate columns.

```
foreach my $hashref ( @homefoldersize ) { 
    $hashref -> {Size} .= $hashref -> {Unit};
    delete $hashref -> {Unit};
}
```

Additionally -as another poster notes - you'll need to set `sep_char` to change the delimiter to `;`.

As an alternative to that - you could probably use a hash slice:

```
@values = @hash{@keys};
```

But `print_hr` does pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

All that is necessary is

```
printf "%s;%s%s\n", @{$_}{qw/ User Size Unit /} for @homefoldersize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the example for Text::CSV posted here: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm

You will need to set `sep_char = ';'` to make it semicolon-separated.

Comment: I read that manual,  still problems in my case tho I get `HASH(0x.....)` in my CSV-file.

Comment: `my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => ';' } );
      $csv->print( $fh1, \@AoH );` is the one I use.

Comment: $csv->print expects an array ref, not a AoH. See the doc in @Barett's answer.

Comment: @NeilHWatson `my $AoH_ref = \@AoH;` Using $AoH_ref does not help in my case.